# How do I refresh only this DIV with a script inside?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i try everything but nothing works.
i want to refresh only this div every 3 seconds.

```
<div id="here"><script src="http://scripts.myradiostream.com/s3/4734/song.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: i think i tried every script about "refresh a specific div"

Comment: what you want to achieve from this? may be that can solve differently

Comment: this script shows what song play now on a shoutcast radio.It works but it doesn't refresh. I just want to refresh it in order to show the other songs.

Comment: "Every script" sounds pretty broad. Can you share even one of your attempts to solve this problem, and the things that do not work with that attempt, and your tries to resolve whatever is not working?

Comment: i tried the ".load(window.location.href + " #here" );"
i tried the ".load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');"
and many other scripts that are mentions in topics about refreshing a specific div.
In many tries the refresh was done but when the script refresh the page and brings only the div #here and nothing else ( html or css).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="here" action="javascript:document.location.reload(3000)"><script src="http://scripts.myradiostream.com/s3/4734/song.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it